# auto type deduction coercion for templated class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have 2 issues in a template class I'm building. I've included example code below. First question is whether I can coerce the auto type deducted for a templated class. i.e.:

auto p = myvar;

where myvar is T<...>, could I force auto to detect Q<...>? This is simplified. Read on for a more clear explanation.

Edited for clarity: Let me explain what I'm doing. And I'd also like to indicate that this style code is working on a large-scale project perfectly well. I am trying to add some features and functions and in addition to smooth out some of the more awkward behaviors.

The code uses templates to perform work on n-dimensional arrays. The template has a top-level class, and a storage class underneath. Passing the storage class into the top level class allows for a top level class which inherits the storage class. So I start with NDimVar, and I have NDimStor. I end up with

```
NDimVar<NDimStor>
```

The class contains NO DATA except for the buffer of data:

```
class NDimStor<size_t... dimensions> {
int buffer[Size<dimensions...>()]
}
```

This makes the address of the class == the address of the buffer. This is key to the whole implementation. Is this an incorrect assumption? (I can see this works on my system without any issues, but perhaps this isn't always the case.)

When I create NDimVar<NDimStor<10,10>> I end up with a 10x10 array.

I have functions for getting pieces of the array, for example:

```
NDimVar<NDimStor<dimensions...>>::RemoveDim & get(int index);
```

This creates a new 1d array of 10 elements out of the 2d 10x10 array:

```
NDimVar<NdimStor<10>>
```

In order to return this as a reference, I use a reinterpret_cast at the location of the data I want. So in this example, get(3) would perform:

```
return reinterpret_cast<NDimVar≤NDimStor<dimensions...>>::RemoveDim&>(buffer[index * DimensionSumBelow<0>()]);
```

DimensionSumBelow<0> returns the sum of elements at dimensions 1+, i.e. 10. So &buffer[30] is the address of the referenced 1d NDimVar.

All of this works very well.

The only issue I have is that I would like to add on overlays. For example, be able to return a reference to a new class:

```
NDimVar<NDimPermute<NDimStor<10,10>,1,0>>
```

that points to the same original location along with a permutation behavior (swapping dimensions). This also works well. But I would like for:

```
auto p = myvar.Permute<1,0>()
```

to create a new copy of myvar with permuted data. This would work if I said:

```
NDimVar<NDimStor<10,10>> p = myvar.Permute<1,0>().
```

I feel that there is some auto type deduction stuff I could do in order to coerce the auto type returned, but I'm not sure. I haven't been able to figure it out.

Thanks again,
Nachum

What I want is:
1. Create temporary overlay classes on my storage, e.g. A_top<A_storage> can return a type called A_top<A_overlay<A_storage>> without creating a new object, it just returns a reference to this type. This changes the way the storage is accessed. The problem is upon a call to auto. I don't want this type to be instantiated directly. Can I modify the return to auto to be an original A_top?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A_storage {
    public:
    float arr[10];
    A_storage () {
    }
    float & el (int index) {
        return arr[index];
    }
};

template <typename T> class A_overlay : T {
    private:
    A_overlay () {
        cout << "A_overlay  ()" << endl;
    }
    A_overlay (const A_overlay  &) {
        cout << "A_overlay  (&)" << endl;
    }
    public:
    using T::arr;
    float & el (int index) {
        return arr[10 - index];
    }
};

template <typename T> class A_top;

template <typename T> class A_top : public T {
    public:
        A_top () {
        }
        A_top<A_overlay<A_storage>> & get () {
            return reinterpret_cast<A_top<A_overlay<A_storage>>&>(*this);
        }
};

using A = A_top<A_storage>;

int main (void) {
    A a;
    auto c = a.get(); // illegal - can i auto type deduce to A_top<A_storage>?
    return 0;
}
```

2. If a function accepts (A_top<A_storage> &) as a parameter, how can I create a conversion function that can cast A_top<A_overlay<A_storage>>& to A_top<A_storage>& ?

Thanks,
Nachum

Comment: If auto is confusing you, just start out by not using it.   Put the type you actually want it to be and let the compiler tell you if something is wrong.  What you are doing is probably way too complex of a problem given your lack of understanding of fundamental parts of C++, though.   I recommend starting with something simpler.  You seem to have multiple layers of confusion which will make any answer to your specific question difficult for you to understand -- and also makes your question difficult to answer because it is somewhat nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

First, your design doesn't look right to me, and I'm not sure if the behaviour is actually well-defined or not. (Probably not.)

In any case, the problem is not with `auto`. The error is caused by the fact that the copy constructor of `A_overlay` is private, while you need it to copy `A_top<A_overlay<A_storage>>` returned by `a.get()` to `auto c`.

(Note that the `auto` in this case obviously gets deduced to `A_top<A_overlay<A_storage>>`, I assume you made a typo when said that it's `A_top<A_storage>`.)

---

Also note that `A_storage` in `A_top::get()` should be replaced with `T`, even if it doesn't change anything in your snippet because you only have `T == A_storage`.

---

> If a function accepts (A_top &) as a parameter, how can I create a conversion function that can cast A_top> to A_top& ?

Ehm, isn't it just this:

```
return reinterpret_cast<A_top<A_storage>&>(obj);
```

Comment: @nachum It doesn't make sense to me. You could make `get()` return `A_top<A_storage>` , but then what's the point of `get()` at all?

Comment: The code is correct. I want the overlay version returned. But I don't want A_overlay to be created on assign. That is why it has a private copy constructor. That is intentional. I want auto to return A_top<A_storage> Even though get() returns a reference of A_top<A_overlay<A_storage>>. Is there any way to manipulate auto type detection to get this behavior? –

Comment: @nachum But they are not convertible. Even `A_top<A_storage> c = a.get()` wouldn't work. Looks like you'd need to use polymorphism.

Comment: this works fine. I have a conversion constructor that copies data over to a new object. Do you know if auto can be coerced? That's most interesting to me.

Comment: @nachum Then why you didn't show that constructor in the question? No, that would defy the purpose of `auto`. Why wouldn't you just change the return type of `.get()` to `A_top<A_storage>`? *"I want the overlay version returned."* is not a valid answer.

Comment: Why is returning the overlay version not a valid answer for you? Please see larger description that I added above. The reasoning is laid out.

Comment: @nachum You have no options anyway. `auto` always gets deduced to the return type and you can't change that.

Answer (score 0):

`reinterpret_cast` should almost never be used. It essentially remove any compiler validation that the types are related. And doing unrelated cast is essentially undefined behavior as it essentially assume that derived classes are always at offset 0...

It does not make any sense to write such code. It is not maintainable and hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. It look like you want to pretend that your `A_top<A_storage>` object is a `A_top<A_overlay<A_storage>>` object instead. **If this is what you want to do, then declare `A` alias as that type.**

In your code, it look like you want to invert the indexing so that item at position 10 is returned when you ask item at position 0 and vice versa. **Do you really think, that it is obvious from your obfuscated code?** Never write such bad code.

Something like

```
class A_overlay {
public:
    float & el (int index) { return arr[10 - index]; }

private:
    A_storage arr;
};
```

would make much more sense than your current code.

- No cast needed.
- Easy to understand.
- Well defined behavior.
- You might keep your job.

And obviously, you would update the following line as appropriate:

```
using A = A_top<A_storage>;
```

Also, if `A_top` has no useful purpose, then why not using `A_overlay` directly? And why are you using template if `A_storage` is not a template? Do you really want to reuse such mess elsewhere in your code base.

**Obviously, your code inheritance does not respect IS-A relationship if your write such code.** So it is clearly a bad design!

Comment: Please see my added description above. The overlays are dynamically added to allow for permutation of permutation, or partial slices of a permuted class. So I can't alias all possibly created templates. My example was too simple, sorry! See if the question is clearer now. Any and all suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Returns proxy instead of pretending that your data is another type. As far as I know, you are relying on undefined behavior by assuming that data has a given layout. This could easily break if for example a virtual function is added or multiple inheritance is used...

Comment: But a proxy is a new class and I desire to refer to my data as a reference would. Keep the simplest C++ semantics for the user. Also, a derived class should work fine. What makes you think it wouldn't?

Comment: I already explain why I think it is bad what you are doing... Essentially, it make the code less clear, less portable and less maintainable. The proxy solution does not add anymore class than the casting but does thing is a standard way instead of abusing the system.